# How to make program sleep until next day

Tags: python, time, sleep

I need my code to stop and wait until the next day. The time does not matter, I just need it to continue when the date changes.

```
currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()

future = datetime.datetime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, 
    (currentDate.day + 1))

time.sleep((future-currentDate).total_seconds())
```

The code pauses but does not continue after

Comment: If the time doesn't matter why not do `time.sleep(24 * 60 * 60)`?

Comment: Op didn't want to sleep for 24 hours.

Comment: The first day it might not sleep for 24 hours but every time after that it will.

Answer (score 2):

Two options here with comments.

First do imports

```py
import datetime
import time
```

- one uses a while loop - probably not a good solution but highlights one way to wait for a condition to be met.

```py
def loop_until_tomorrow():
    """ Will use a while loop to iterate until tomorrow """

    #get current date
    currentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    # loop attempts 
    times = 0 
    # this will loop infiniatly if condition is never met 
    while True:
        # increment by one each iteration
        times += 1
        #get date now
        now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        if currentDate != now:
            # return when condition met             
            print("\nDay has changed")
            return 
        else:            
            # print attempts and sleep here to avoid program hanging 
            print(f"Attempt: {times}".ljust(13) + " - Not tomorrow yet!", end="\r")
            time.sleep(5)
```

- the other - sleeps for the amount of seconds from now till tomorrow

```py
def sleep_until_tomorrow():

    """wait till tomorrow using time.sleep"""
    
    #get date now
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    #get tomorrows date 
    tomorrow_date = now.date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    #set to datetime
    tomorrow_datetime = datetime.datetime(year=tomorrow_date.year, month=tomorrow_date.month, day=tomorrow_date.day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
    #get seconds
    seconds_til_tomorrow = (tomorrow_datetime-now).total_seconds()
    #sleep
    time.sleep(seconds_til_tomorrow)
```

Comment: @CodeMonkey - very true

Answer (score 0):

You can use schedule for that purpose, which will give you the flexibility to refactore the code when needed without having to write a chunck of code.

```py
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending
import time

#just to give you the idea on how to implement the module. 
@repeat(every().day.at("7:15"))
def remind_me_its_a_new_day():
    print("Hey there it's a new day! ")

while True:
    run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```